# How to apply a color gradient to a Rectangle primitive?

Tags: graphics, manipulate, color, output

How can we apply a color gradient (say "Rainbow") to a **Rectangle** primitive ?  Of course, I searched the documentation :

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rectangle.html,

and also the site :

[How to colorize a rectangle with a given color function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17947/how-to-colorize-a-rectangle-with-a-given-color-function)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142179/gradient-fill-using-graphics-in-mathematica

but didn't found something clear about the **Rectangle** primitive.  I have the impression that this graphics primitive cannot have a color gradient applied to it.

Here's a MWE code to work with (the Red color in the Rectangle primitive should be remplaced with an *horizontal* 50% translucent "rainbow" gradient) :

```
SpectreVisible = Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{380, -1}, {700, 8}]}];

Manipulate[
Show[
    SpectreVisible,
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, {0, 7}},
    AspectRatio -> 1,
    Frame -> True,
    GridLines -> Automatic,
    GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed],
    Ticks -> Automatic,
    ImageSize -> {600, 600}
    ],
FrameMargins -> None
]
```

The Manipulate code isn't essential here, but that rectangle would be used inside a Manipulate box.

**EDIT :** The possible duplicates aren't helping much.  The codes are very complicated there, and doesn't address the issue with a simple Rectangle primitive.

Comment: Use `Raster[]` instead.

Comment: Why ?  Rectangle can't have a gradient color ?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/N5eK4.png, from http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6562/how-can-i-create-a-rectangular-graphic-with-curved-edges

Comment: These codes aren't obvious at all !  I'm unable to define a simple rectangle (with coordinates) using ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", and a transparency.  Mathematica is so ackward to use !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Rectangle` cannot have a gradient color.

Here's one way to construct such a gradient. Under the hood it is using `Polygon` with the `VertexColors` option.

```
Graphics[ChartElementData["GradientRectangle", 
   "ColorScheme" -> "Rainbow", 
   "GradientOrigin" -> Left][{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]]
```

`{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}` corresponds to `{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}` for the rectangle.

[image]

Comment: I cannot search `ChartElementData` in documentation and I can search `GradientRectangle` either.If you put some specification about how to get it.I'll appreciate you.

Comment: This code works very well.  It's far from obvious, though.

Comment: Ok,I have found that.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps ou mean this?

```
    Show[SetAlphaChannel[LinearGradientImage["Rainbow"], 0.5], Axes -> True]
```

[image]

---

The version is derived from J.M.

```
Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], 
  Raster[{Range[0, 1, 1/100]}, {{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]}]
```

[image]

Comment: How do you add a transparency effet (say 50%) ?  And how do you define the edges coordinates in a graphics ?

Comment: Hmm, MMA 7 doesn't seem to know the `LinearGradientImage` command

Comment: Feel so sorry to hear you use 7.0

Comment: Well, nobody is perfect.  Upgrading MMA implies that I upgrade the whole computer with its OS.  It is too costly.  Not worth all the troubles for me.  So does that mean that there is no solution in my case ?  I can't believe that I can't do a simple rectangle inside a graphics with an horizontal gradient applied to it !

Comment: If you use 7.0,that mean the option of `ColorOutput` does works?

Comment: @Cham, if you're stuck on 7, then why not use `Raster[]`? That will still work.

Comment: @J.M., I wasn't able to make it to work.  The code appears to be pretty complicated, to add the Rainbow gradient, with a transparency, etc...  At least, the code below is working great.

Comment: @Cham, I'm not at a computer right now, but try this: `Graphics[Raster[Range[0, 1, 1/100], {{0, 3}, {0, 1}}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]]`.

Comment: @J.M., well, it gives a simple white square.  Nothing is visible inside.  What is the meaning of the Range numbers ?

Comment: @J.M., the `ChartElementData`is working very nicely.  It may be the solution that I'll adopt.  This thing is very new to me, and I don't understand what it is, yet.

Comment: @Cham I have update the J.M.'s Raster

Comment: Sorry, I missed a necessary brace, @Cham. Try `Graphics[Raster[{Range[0, 1, 1/100]}, {{0, 3}, {0, 1}}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]]`. First argument is for generating the gradient; second argument dictates the size of the rectangle.

Comment: @J.M. Invisible still~

Comment: @J.M., yep, I confirm that it's still a white square.

Comment: @Cham The J.M.'s meaning maybe `Graphics[Raster[{Range[0,1,1/100]},{{0,0},{1,1}},ColorFunction->"Rainbow"]]`.It very clean.You take the all credit.And thanks for your guidance.

Comment: @yode, and J.M., ok, now it's working.  But adding a transparency (say `Opacity[0.25]`) gives a problem :  the gradient is now made of lots of thin rectangles with their edges visible.  It's really ugly !

Comment: Alright, I'll try on my computer later; clearly I did not get the syntax of `Raster[]` right.

Comment: @J.M., as I just said, try this to add a transparency : `Graphics[{Opacity[0.25], 
  Raster[{Range[0, 1, 1/100]}, {{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]}]`.  This is terrible !

Comment: @Cham Really?It's beautiful in here like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qi6aW.jpg).Or you can change the 1/100 be more smaller like 0.001.Then the picture will like more smooth.

Comment: @yode, just resize that block.  Don't you get this : http://s17.postimg.org/4chebkzlb/yuk.jpg ?  Changing to 0.01/100 is actually worst (darker tones).

Comment: @Cham I couldn't reproduce your black block.

Comment: @yode, it's probably a bug or a limitation of my version 7.  Anyway, the `ChartElementData`is working perfectly.  So I do have a complete solution.

Answer (score 2):

I may have found a solution, but it needs some improvements :

```
Spectre = RegionPlot[380 < x < 700, {x, 380, 700}, {y, -1, 8}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["Rainbow"][x]]];

Manipulate[
    Show[Spectre,
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, {0, 7}}, 
    AspectRatio -> 1,
    Frame -> True,
    GridLines -> Automatic, 
    GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed],
    Ticks -> Automatic, 
    ImageSize -> {600, 600}
],
FrameMargins -> None]
```

Preview :

[image: gradient fill]

The problem with this code is that the color region doesn't show the grid behind it.  The grid should be above it.

Also, the color tones are much too strong.  How do you add a transparency effect to the gradient ?

And lastly, I had to define the range **{y, -1, 8}** instead of **{y, 0, 7}**.  Is there a better way of doing this, so the rectangle doesn't have a white "margin" below and above it ?

Comment: If you specify `PlotRange` inside `RegionPlot` you won't get the white margin. You also won't get it if you set `PlotRangePadding -> None` inside `Show`.